# How can I set values by index using .loc for pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have df with for example 2 columns: Col1, Col2, I want to select and set values as such

```
df.loc[df['Col1'] == "SomeValue", 'Col2'][beginningIndex:endingIndex] = np.nan
```

however this does not actually set the values, when I access the same location later, the values have not changed.

Comment: That's call chained indexing, and wouldn't work. You should try `df.loc[df.index.to_series().between(beginIdx, endIdx) & df['Col1'].eq("SomeValue"),'Col2'] = np.nan`.

Comment: will this work? instead of df.index.series().between(begin,end), I have pd.Series(df.index.tolist()[begin:end]), also is there a faster more efficient way for this? This is too slow for my dataframe. Thanks